# Why are C I/O functions inconsistent among themselves?

Tags: c, language-design

Consistency is fundamental property in a code base, let alone in a programming language that eventually turned out to be the most used in the world.

There are two families of I/O functions in C: formatted and unformatted. These are:

```
int fprintf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...);
int vfprintf(FILE *stream, const char *format, va_list ap);
```

And

```
int fputc(int c, FILE *stream);
int fputs(const char *s, FILE *stream);
int putc(int c, FILE *stream);
```

`*fprintf` seems to go for the `(where, what)` ordering whereas `*put*` for `(what, where)`; same holds for input functions. Why is the **`stream`** parameter at **different positions**? Are there any **historical**/**design** motivations for such choice?

Comment: Well for one, since the `printf` family takes a variable number of arguments, you couldn't stick a `FILE *stream` param at the end of it.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: It could have `fprintf(const char *format, FILE *stream, ...)`

Comment: Languages evolve. Not every quirk is the product of explicit design decision. To quote the preface of the 2nd edition of K&R: "C, like any other language, has its blemishes."

Comment: Which would be inconsistent with plain `printf`, which has the `format` and varargs next to each other.

Comment: You can speculate (with @ColonelThirtyTwo 's observation about the variable number of arguments to `printf` a reasonable guess), but unless the person who wrote that part of the standard library wrote down their motivation somewhere, you are speculating about the motivation of a person who is quite possibly dead (or if alive, unlikely to remember -- I don't always recall some of my design decisions from just last year, let alone 30 years ago).

Comment: It's not clear what kind of an answer you're expecting here. If you're looking for someone to say that C's stdio had the dubious benefit of some of the worst library API design in the history of computer programming I'm happy to volunteer, but the discussion is futile. If you're looking for a hidden reason, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

There is no good choice for `fprintf` family, because functions that take variable-argument lists need to take the "fixed" portion of their parameters before the variadic part:

- Sticking `stream` in the middle, as in `fprintf(const char *format, FILE *stream, ...)` would be inconsistent with `printf`, where formatted values follow the format string immediately. It would stay inconsistent with `fputc` family, too.
- Sticking `stream` into the variadic part, as in `fprintf(const char *format, ...)`, is theoretically possible, but it would be inefficient, because you'd need to get to the last argument before you can start writing to your stream.

`fputc` family, on the other hand, could be rewritten as `fputc(FILE *stream, int c)`. However, its precursor `putc` was mentioned in the original version of K&R book ([pdf](https://ia801303.us.archive.org/1/items/TheCProgrammingLanguageFirstEdition/The%20C%20Programming%20Language%20First%20Edition%20[UA-07].pdf), scroll to page 152) so the authors of the standard decided to stick to the convention when adding the no-macro `fputc` function to the library.

Comment: The good, and obvious, choice, would have been to put the `FILE *` *first* throughout `stdio`, but somebody had probably already screwed up by putting it last in `fread()/fwrite()`, so here we are.

Comment: @EJP I did not find `fread`/`fwrite` in the first edition of K&R, only `putc` and `fputs` (no `fputc` or `puts`, though). That's why I think this is the origin of this screw-up. And yes, I completely agree with you that this is indeed a screw-up.